# How to make x axis labels work in d3 with react?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, label, ordinal

here is an example of my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {scaleOrdinal, axisBottom, select} from 'd3';

export default class BarChart extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.renderSvg = this.renderSvg.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderSvg();
  }

  renderSvg() {
    const margin = 20;
    const width = 400;
    const height = 800;
    const data = ["why", "aren't", "you", "working"]
      .map((title) => ({title}));

    // create scalar for x axis
    const x = scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(data.map(({title}) => title))
      .range([0, width]);

    const xAxis = axisBottom(x);

    // create svg and append graph
    const svg = select("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height + margin)
      .append("g")

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
  }

  render() {
    const {width, height, className} = this.props;
    return <div className="body">
      <svg className="svg" />
    </div>
  }
}
```

I have followed the example at this site: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3259783 pretty closely as far as I can tell, but I can't get it to display the labels where they are expected to be at regular/even intervals. Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to using d3.

Comment: you translate the x-axis to the bottom pixel of the svg `height`. The ticks and labels are drawn below this position. Have a look with the Developer Tools and you will see the ticks and texts are part of the svg. Try `height*0.5`

Comment: The issue is not that they aren't visible, they are visible, they are just all on top of eachother. The words are not equally spaced apart which is what I am expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the conversion from d3v3 to d3v4/5.

The `d3.scale.ordinal()` (v3) is used for a number of scale types and determined by the `rangeX()` call you make.

In d3v5 `d3.scaleOrdinal()` means an ordinal scale and maps an ordinal domain to an ordinal range. https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/#scaleOrdinal You have only set the range to a 2 value array. So each domain value is alternated on the 2 range values.

Here is a d3v5 example. I have adjusted the height to see something when run. Use the Developer Tools to see the alternating translation of the axis ticks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
<svg class="svg"/>
</div>
<script>
function renderSvg() {
  const margin = 20;
  const width = 400;
  const height = 100;
  const data = ["why", "aren't", "you", "working"]
    .map((title) => ({title}));

  // create scalar for x axis
  const x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(data.map(({title}) => title))
    .range([0, width]);

  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

  // create svg and append graph
  const svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height + margin)
    .append("g");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
}

renderSvg();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The example code uses `.rangePoints([0, width])` and that converts in d3v5 to `d3.scalePoint()`. Now the ordinal domain is mapped to a continuous range.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
<svg class="svg"/>
</div>
<script>
function renderSvg() {
  const margin = 20;
  const width = 400;
  const height = 100;
  const data = ["why", "aren't", "you", "working"]
    .map((title) => ({title}));

  // create scalar for x axis
  const x = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(data.map(({title}) => title))
    .range([0, width]);

  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

  // create svg and append graph
  const svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height + margin)
    .append("g");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
}

renderSvg();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```